Fastest "shift and duplicate" operation
Arch is SuperH, specifically SH-2. I don't know the name of this operation, but I have been calling it "shift and duplicate". Effectively what I am looking for is:
0x0000AB12 -> 0xABAB1212

Ie, instead of drawing two pixels normally (with values of AB and 12), I am drawing two pixels but scaled 2x along the x axis.
Unfortunately I need this to be extremely fast. I was originally doing
mov r6, r8
shll8 r6
add r8, r6

To expand a byte into a word, (getting a single byte at a time) but from my testing, getting a word and writing a long per loop would be much faster, assuming I can solve this "shift and duplicate" issue in few enough instructions.
(loop unrolling also of course in all test cases)
Here is my naive attempt:
# Move r6 to a temporary register, to be used later for the lower byte
mov r6, r8

# Extract the upper byte
shlr8 r6
extu.b r6, r6
# r6 is now: 0x000000AB

# Duplicate the upper byte and shift into position
mov r6, r9
shll8 r6
add r9, r6
shll16 r6
# r6 is now: 0xABAB0000

# duplicate the lower byte
extu.b r8, r8
mov r8, r9
shll8 r8
add r9, r8
# r8 is now: 0x00001212

add r8, r6
# r6 is now: 0xABAB1212

12 instructions! Ouch! There must be a faster way to do this that I'm just not seeing, perhaps with some logical operations.
The SH-2 does have XTRCT, which extracts the middle 32 bits from two registers, and SWAP.B and SWAP.W, if those could help at all.

I have shll8 r6 /* r6 = 0x00AB1200 */; swap.b r6, r6 /* r6 = 0x00AB0012 */; mov r6, r8; shll8 r8 /* r8 = 0xAB001200 */; or r8, r6 /* r6 = 0xABAB1212 */

Wow, thank you! That works perfectly. Only 5 instructions!
